# Accepting user entered strings in html pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a Language Translator but that translates hard coded strings in a html page using java script. I would to make it flexible by allowing user enter a string into a textbox/textarea and my app can then translate it for the user.

Any help would be appreciable :)

Heres my code: (please note to enter your own API key)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    google.load("language", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var content = document.getElementById('content');
      // Setting the text in the div.
      content.innerHTML = '<div id="text">Hola, me alegro mucho de verte.<\/div><div id="translation"/>';

      // Grabbing the text to translate
      var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

      // Translate from Spanish to English, and have the callback of the request

      google.language.translate(text, 'es', 'en', function(result) {
        var translated = document.getElementById("translation");
        if (result.translation) {
          translated.innerHTML = result.translation;
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="content">Loading...</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TonioElGringo  lol.  I would like to know that how can I integrate a functionality through which I can make a user enter a string/sentence to be translated into a textbox and then user can click on a button and finally then the initialize method will work so as to display the translated string. ALL THIS using javascript only :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google translate api
You can make calls to the api and get a translated version. Refer [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java)

Put this in html

```
<button type="button" onclick="initialize()">Translate</button>
```

And this in your initialize function if content is a textbox

```
content.value = "your translated text"
```

This will change your text in the same box

Comment: hehe.. I am already using it. Though I have a simple doubt in mind of accepting user input with help of javascript, processing it and then displaying the translated string all on the same page. Also I am in no mood of using JSON :P

Comment: well i knew this one of how to call a javascript function on a button click :) What I need to know is .. how can I accept user entered string in a textbox and then process it instead of the hard coded text to translate. I am also confused with as how can I provide the above functionality without loading the whole page again (sort of a auto postback feature?). I want to display the translated text right below the original text entered by the user.

Comment: Check if this is what u want!!

Comment: Please refer to my comment above ^ :) btw Thanks for the second input (content.value to replace the original text :D )

Comment: Add the initial text with the new text and put as your new value